# Moving all contents of a directory to another in Python

Tags: python, glob, shutil

I've been trying to figure this out for hours with no luck.  I have a list of directories that have subdirectories and other files of their own.  I'm trying to traverse through all of them and move all of their content to a specific location.  I tried shutil and glob but I couldn't get it to work.  I even tried to run shell commands using `subprocess.call` and that also did not work either.  I understand that it didn't work because I couldn't apply it properly but I couldn't find any solution that moves all contents of a directory to another.

```
files = glob.glob('Food101-AB/*/')
dest = 'Food-101/'

if not os.path.exists(dest):
    os.makedirs(dest)
    subprocess.call("mv Food101-AB/* Food-101/", shell=True)

    # for child in files:
    #   shutil.move(child, dest)
```

I'm trying to move everything in Food101-AB to Food-101

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[shutil](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module of the standart library is the way to go:

```py
>>> import shutil
>>> shutil.move("Food101-AB", "Food-101")
```

If you don't want to move `Food101-AB` folder itself, try using this:

```py
import shutil
import os

for i in os.listdir("Food101-AB"):
    shutil.move(os.path.join("Food101-AB", i), "Food-101")
```

For more information about `move` function:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.move

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `call` function to `run` in order to retrieve the `stdout`, `stderr` and `return code` for your shell command:

```
from subprocess import run, CalledProcessError
source_dir = "full/path/to/src/folder"
dest_dir = "full/path/to/dest/folder"
try:
    res = run(["mv", source_dir, dest_dir], check=True, capture_output=True)
except CalledProcessError as ex:
    print(ex.stdout, ex.stderr, ex.returncode)
```